# Unable to run EXE file from network share

Tags: permissions, network-share, windows-10

I have several user machines that are unable to run EXE files from certain network shares. I have verified all NTFS and Share permissions (screenshot below). It doesn't matter if I double click, or through batch file, or Run as Administrator all fail and say "`Windows cannot access \\exchange\signatures\file.exe`" with details saying "`You do not have permission to access \\exchange\signatures\file.exe`"

permissions

[image: permissions]

It doesn't seem tied to a specific user. If I attempt to run the file from my computer which is in the same OU it works fine, but if I sign in as myself on this other machine, it gives the error message stated above. This share has been around for many years and we have never had problems accessing it before but this new batch of computers seems to be having issues with this location. The computer is running Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB

I am able to copy the file from the share locally and run, however this is does not actually resolve the issue as the file MUST be run from its network location so it syncs the proper contents.

Any thoughts on what might be interfering with the ability to properly run these files? It's almost like its something with the computers themselves as these machines are in the same OU as other machines that work fine both machines are running same OS and it happens no matter what user is signed into the machine.

Comment: Anti-virus software, perhaps?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you! AV appeared to be the problem. I originally did not think of that as all computers in our domain have same AV endpoint client and configuration and this was only affecting one model. It appears that something during the imaging process was causing the AV install not to be recognized such that our AV was running and so was Windows Defender (defender normally automatically disables itself once it detects another AV) after uninstall and reinstalling the AV client access was restored.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped.  Welcome to Server Fault!  I've posted a formal answer for you to accept if you wish to do so.  You are also welcome to post and accept your own answer if you wish to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysterious access denied errors are often caused by malfunctioning or misconfigured anti-virus software.

In this particular instance, the OP has confirmed that the problem was a third-party anti-virus product which was failing to disable Windows Defender on the affected machines.  Apparently the two anti-virus products were interfering with one another.  Reinstalling the third-party product resolved the problem.